# Implementing a `TryGetValue` method that optionally returns a `ref` in C#

Tags: c#, ref

### Background

I am trying to implement a C# function that is similar to `Dictionary`'s `bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)`, however, the out value needs to be a `ref` to a struct.

It would hypothetically look like this:

```cs
bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out ref TValue value) { /* Implementation */ }
```

Essentially, the above function accepts a `TValue**` (a double managed pointer). The compiler surely doesn't accept the code above, so I have found several workarounds:

### Workaround 1

```cs
ref TValue TryGetValue(TKey key, out bool found) { /* Implementation */ }
```

If the key is found, it returns a `ref` to the value, and set `found` to `true`. Otherwise, return a `ref` to a dummy object, and set `found` to `false`.

However, this is not ideal as I can't do something in a single if-statement like I would have with `Dictionary`'s `TryGetValue`:

```cs
if (dict.TryGetValue("key", out var val)
{
    doSomething(val);
}
```

I would need to do:

```cs
ref var val = ref myDict.TryGetValue("key", out bool found);
if (found)
{
    doSomething(ref val);
}
```

Further, due to my old C# version, the `out` parameter `found` would pollute the scope of the returned value `val`, so that I can't do:

```
ref var val = ref myDict.TryGetValue("key", out bool found);
if (found)
{
    doSomething(ref val);
}
return ref val; // Not accepted by the compiler
```

(I know this can be fixed by the `scoped` keyword, but I am stuck with an older C# version :sad: )

### Workaround 2

I have made myself a `Nullable`-like type for `ref var`s, which has the properties `Value` and `HasValue`. It is implemented as `ref struct` that encapsulate a span (I have to work with an older version of C# so no support for `ref` fields).

```cs
public readonly ref struct OptionalRef<T>
{
    private readonly Span<T> m_storage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an optional ref from a ref.
    /// It is the caller's responsibility to ensure that the optional ref
    /// cannot outlive the referred object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public OptionalRef(ref T value)
    {
        m_storage = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref value, 1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an optional ref that references the first element in a span (if the span is empty),
    /// or a null ref (if the span is empty).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="span"></param>
    public OptionalRef(Span<T> span)
    {
        m_storage = span;
    }
    
    public bool HasValue
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        get => !m_storage.IsEmpty;
    }

    public ref T Value
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        get => ref m_storage[0];
    }
}
```

Now I can do the following:

```cs
OptionalRef<TValue> TryGetValue(TKey key);
```

And I originally hoped that I can do some pattern matching to get things in one line:

```cs
if (myDict.TryGetValue("key") is { HasValue: true, Value: ref var myVal })
{
    doSomething(ref myVal);
}
```

But this doesn't work either, and the compiler complains about the `ref var` pattern (using just `var` is fine, but doesn't serve my purpose):

```
A property subpattern requires a reference to the property or field to be matched, e.g. '{ Name: var a }'
```

And also the order of pattern checking is undefined according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#property-pattern).

> The order in which subpatterns are matched is not specified, and a failed match may not match all subpatterns at runtime.

So my question is, is there a better/more elegant way of achieving this?

Comment: First question: why has to be a ref to a struct? I mean, the benefit would arise if *all* the Dictionary will use ref structs inside its code.

Comment: @MarioVernari It is used for an [entity component system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system). I implemented some dictionary internally backed by array blocks of structs (for cache performance), so a `ref` return is necessary. You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/Puffercat-Industries/com.puffercat.uxt/blob/8bedee3c9e3163e44f04fa84a6833c95639df363/Runtime/ECS/Core/EntityRegistry.cs#L132)

Comment: Can you actually benchmark all that? If so, you could try via reflection: have a look at this method: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs,392

Comment: However, I'm not sure the reflection tools would pay the bill, after all.

Comment: What you are trying to do might not be possible. See the [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluerefornullref) how Microsoft does it.